# Webpack alias is not recognized by flow

Tags: webpack, eslint, flowtype

I'm having some trouble with webpack aliases and having it play nicely with flow.

I have the alias:

```
    alias: {
        vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
        puma: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/app/stores/clothes'),
    },
```

and I'm using it within my components by importing as such:

```
     import components from "puma/components"
```

For my flowconfig, I have it setup as:

```
 module.name_mapper='^puma\/.*' -> 'puma/\1'
```

and I'm really unsure of how this OCaml type of regex works... and I need some help.

The end goal of this post would be to be able to resolve the error:

```
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ puma. Required module not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

I just didn't quite understand what was going on in the `name_mapper`, and I still don't *fully understand* it, but my guess is this:

flow parses through your files, and then when it gets to the import, I think it does some checking to its `name_mappers` to see if the import syntax is an alias or needs to be mapped to something else. In this case, when it got to `puma`, there is no directory named `puma` in the codebase but there happened to be a `name_mapper` in the `.flowconfig` that fit its regex, so it went down the mapped path to `assets/app/puma/clothes`.

The regex I applied wasn't right, and I ended up using something similar like: `module.name_mapper='^puma' -> 'assets/app/stores/clothes'` to get it to work.

One question I do have... is how big of an impact does this have on performance? Does flow now check every import against the `name_mapper` to see if there's a mapping? Does adding new `name_mapper` greatly decrease the parsing speed of flow?

If anyone knows, I'd be very curious in hearing it.